# Pyqt - Add a QMenuBar to a QMainWindow which is in another class

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have 2 classes : MainWindow() and Menubar(). MainWindow() is a QMainWindow and Menubar is a QMenuBar.
I don't know how I can add the menu bar to the main window.

With the QToolBar, I can make something like this :

`self.toolbar = Toolbar()
 self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)`

But with the QMenubar, there isn't any function like "addMenuBar()".

So I can't figure out with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QMainWindow` comes with its default `QMenuBar`, but you can set a new one with `QMainWindow.setMenuBar()`

More informations in the [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html)

Comment: You ***can*** set a new one with ```QMainWindow.setMenuBar()```